# Javascript : how to move from prototype management to the concept of classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, prototype

I will have a new question. Previously, I used a vanilla javascript project. In this project, we made "object" by modifying the prototype. This code was not optimal, I am aware of it, but it worked.

Technologies evolve and so do people. Now, I would like to use the notion of class and Typescript. I created a whole set of classes that correspond to the old ones, but with new features and cleaner code. I would like to know if I can make the existing cohexist exist with the new code (without touching the code).

Here is my old code : https://codepen.io/Answerrer/pen/YzyeNpe

```
function declareClass(classModel, version) {

  if (typeof classModel !== 'function') {
    throw classModel + ' cannot be used as a class as it is not a function';
  }

  if(window.myClasses === undefined) {
    window.myClasses = {};
  }

  window.myClasses[classModel.name] = classModel;

  classModel.prototype._version   = version || '1.0';
  classModel.getVersion =  function() {
    return this.prototype._version;
  };
};

function declareChildClass(subClass, superClass, version) {

  declareClass(subClass, version);

  if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass);
  }
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } });
  if (superClass) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}

  subClass.prototype._super = superClass.prototype;
};

(function() {

  let proto = a.prototype;
  window.declareClass(a, 'A1')

  function a(id, properties) {
    this.id = id;
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  proto.echo = function() {
    console.log('ID [' + this.id + ']');
    console.log('Properties');
    console.log(this.properties);
  }


})();

(function() {
  window.declareChildClass(b, window.myClasses.a, 'B2')

  function b(id) {
    window.myClasses.a.call(this, 'B' + id, {})
  }
})();

var a = new window.myClasses.a('TestA', {data: 'test'}),
    b = new window.myClasses.b('X');

a.echo();
b.echo();
```

Here is the code for class A that I recoded. I would like to use this class without touching up the code I have in object B. The code of the declareClass and declareChildClass functions can be modified.

```
export default class A {
    id:string;
    properties:{};

    constructor(id:string, properties:{}) {
        this.id = id;
        this.properties = properties
    }

    echo() {
        console.log('ID [' + this.id + ']');
        console.log('Properties');
        console.log(this.properties);
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea, I'm interested. If this is not explicit enough I will try to give more information.

Thank you so much.

Comment: JavaScript also has classes, and they work similarly to those in TypeScript. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Typescript is only there to add concepts (such as data typing) to help coding. I should not have indicated that I was using Typescript because, if I had used classes in Javascript Vanilla, without overlapping, the porting does not differ. After I just found that I had not put my new code that I want. I will modify my post.

Comment: Yes you can. But can you maybe tell us what difficulty have you encountered that prevent you from doing that, or maybe not block but uncomfortable. If no then you should be able to just use it all right.

Comment: @hackape My main difficulty is to make sure that the next line, always works without modifying the call in the old class B and that my code calls my new class A (in order to inherit my new class) . 
window.myClasses.a.call(this, 'B' + id, {}). In addition if I have an overload of methods in my class B I would like them to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've tested replacing your ES5 old prototype base `a` function with new ES6 `class a`. It raise the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor a cannot be invoked without 'new'

Expand this snippet to test:

```js
function declareClass(classModel, version) {

  if (typeof classModel !== 'function') {
    throw classModel + ' cannot be used as a class as it is not a function';
  }

  if(window.myClasses === undefined) {
    window.myClasses = {};
  }

  window.myClasses[classModel.name] = classModel;

  classModel.prototype._version   = version || '1.0';
  classModel.getVersion =  function() {
    return this.prototype._version;
  };
};

function declareChildClass(subClass, superClass, version) {

  declareClass(subClass, version);

  if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass);
  }
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } });
  if (superClass) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}

  subClass.prototype._super = superClass.prototype;
};

(function() {

  class a {
    constructor(id, properties) {
        this.id = id;
        this.properties = properties
    }

    echo() {
        console.log('ID [' + this.id + ']');
        console.log('Properties');
        console.log(this.properties);
    }
  }

  window.declareClass(a, 'A1')

})();

(function() {
  window.declareChildClass(b, window.myClasses.a, 'B2')

  function b(id) {
    window.myClasses.a.call(this, 'B' + id, {})
  }
})();

var a = new window.myClasses.a('TestA', {data: 'test'}),
    b = new window.myClasses.b('X');

a.echo();
b.echo();
```

It originates from this line: `window.myClasses.a.call(this, 'B' + id, {}).`

Because `myClasses.a` is a ES6 class, it doesn't support being called without `new` keywords. Quite unfortunately there's no workaround for this issue right inside vanilla JS.

But since you're using TS, you can set the transpile target to `ES5` to force converting the shiny `class` syntax back to old school prototype base function. The result will be:

```
var a = /** @class */ (function () {
    function a(id, properties) {
        this.id = id;
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    a.prototype.echo = function () {
        console.log('ID [' + this.id + ']');
        console.log('Properties');
        console.log(this.properties);
    };
    return a;
}());
```

And that error is gone, expand this snippet to test:

```js
function declareClass(classModel, version) {

  if (typeof classModel !== 'function') {
    throw classModel + ' cannot be used as a class as it is not a function';
  }

  if(window.myClasses === undefined) {
    window.myClasses = {};
  }

  window.myClasses[classModel.name] = classModel;

  classModel.prototype._version   = version || '1.0';
  classModel.getVersion =  function() {
    return this.prototype._version;
  };
};

function declareChildClass(subClass, superClass, version) {

  declareClass(subClass, version);

  if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass);
  }
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } });
  if (superClass) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}

  subClass.prototype._super = superClass.prototype;
};

(function() {

  "use strict";
  var a = /** @class */ (function () {
      function a(id, properties) {
          this.id = id;
          this.properties = properties;
      }
      a.prototype.echo = function () {
          console.log('ID [' + this.id + ']');
          console.log('Properties');
          console.log(this.properties);
      };
      return a;
  }());


  window.declareClass(a, 'A1')

})();

(function() {
  window.declareChildClass(b, window.myClasses.a, 'B2')

  function b(id) {
    window.myClasses.a.call(this, 'B' + id, {})
  }
})();

var a = new window.myClasses.a('TestA', {data: 'test'}),
    b = new window.myClasses.b('X');

a.echo();
b.echo();
```

Conclusion, yes you can mix TS code with old JS code and make them work together. But you need to change the TS code a bit to align with some of the old paradigm, like you don't use module in old code, just global variables. You might want to ditch module in TS too.

```
class a {
    id:string;
    properties:{};

    constructor(id:string, properties:{}) {
        this.id = id;
        this.properties = properties
    }

    echo() {
        console.log('ID [' + this.id + ']');
        console.log('Properties');
        console.log(this.properties);
    }
}

;(window as any).declareClass(a, 'A1');
```

Or, if you still prefer using module, then you need a bridge code on TS side.

**bridgeCode.ts**

```
import a from './myClassA.ts';

;(window as any).declareClass(a, 'A1');
```

Comment: I will try what you suggest to me. We agree that the old code was not necessarily well coded, but it had the merit of working ;). Precisely, the goal of the redesign is to try to have cleaner code. Once I have worked the old with the new, I will make a second pass to modify the old code to make it cleaner. I'll keep you posted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestions (@hackape) made me move forward on babywearing. My "adapter" which makes it possible to make the bridge between the new and the old code is in Typescript / ES6 (I must not start again in badly written code). As a result, certain things are illogical, can cause concern and Typescript prohibits certain things. Not changing the old code at all was a bit utopian and a bit too complex I think.

So, here is the code for my "adapter":

```
export class ClassesAdapter {
  public declaredClasses = new Map<string, Function>();

  /**
   * Declare a new class
   * @param classModel Class (function)
   * @param version Class version
   */
  declareClass(classModel: Function, version: string): void {
    if (classModel instanceof Function) {
      this.declaredClasses.set(classModel.name, classModel);
      classModel.prototype._version = version || '1.0';
      classModel.prototype.getVersion = function(): string {
        return this._version;
      };
    } else {
      throw classModel + ' cannot be used as a class as it is not a function';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Declare child class (extends)
   * @param subClass Child class (function)
   * @param superClass Super class (function)
   * @param version Child version
   */
  declareChildClass(subClass: Function, superClass: Function, version: string): void {
    this.declareClass(subClass, version);

    this.assignSuperClass(superClass, subClass);
  }

  assignSuperClass(superClass: Function, subClass: Function): void {
    if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) {
      throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' +
        typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
      constructor: {
        value: subClass,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
      }
    });
    if (superClass) {
      if (Object.setPrototypeOf) {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass);
      } else {
        subClass.prototype.__proto__ = superClass;
      }
    }
    subClass.prototype._super = superClass.prototype;
  }

  getClass(className: string): Function | undefined {
    let f = undefined;
    if (this.declaredClasses) {
      f = this.declaredClasses.get(className);
    }
    return f;
  }
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    classMnr?: ClassesAdapter;
  }
}

window.classMnr = new ClassesAdapter();
```

Therefore, in my old Javascript I just need to make the following replacement (my old code) :

```
classMnr.declareChildClass(B, classMnr.A, '1.0');
```

By (new code) :

```
window.classMnr.declareChildClass(B, window.classMnr.getClass('A'), '1');
```

And (old code) :

```
var a = new window.myClasses.a('TestA', {data: 'test'}),
```

By (new code) :

```
const AClass = window.qlcClassMnr.getClass('A');
const AObject = new AClass('TestA', {data: 'test'});
```